# Proof verification of $x_n = {1\over2^2}+{2\over3^2}+\cdots+{n\over(n+1)^2}$ diverges by the negation of Cauchy

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, cauchy-sequences

> Let $\{x_n\}$ denote a sequence:
>   $$
> x_n = {1\over2^2}+{2\over3^2}+\cdots+{n\over(n+1)^2}
> $$
>   Show that $\{x_n\}$ diverges using the negation of Cauchy criterion.

I would like to kindly request a verification of the below.

---

Start with the negation of the definition of Cauchy criterion:
$$
\exists \epsilon > 0\ \forall N\in\Bbb N: \exists n, m > N \land |x_n-x_m| \ge \epsilon
$$

First let $m>n$, then:
$$
\begin{align}
|x_n - x_m| = |x_m-x_n| &= \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^m\frac{k}{(k+1)^2}\right| \stackrel{x_k>0}{=} \\
&= \sum_{k=n+1}^m\frac{k}{(k+1)^2} \ge \\ 
&\ge \sum_{k=n+1}^m \frac{k}{(2k)^2} = \\ 
&=\sum_{k=n+1}^m \frac{1}{4k}
\end{align}
$$

Chose $m = 2n$:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n+1}^{m} \frac{1}{4k} &= \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{4k} \ge \\ &\ge \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{8n} = \\
&= n\cdot\frac{1}{8n} = \\
&= {1\over 8}
\end{align}
$$
Thus:
$$
|x_n - x_m| \ge {1\over 8}
$$

Chose $\epsilon = {1\over 8}$:
$$
\exists \epsilon = {1\over 8}\ \forall N \in \Bbb N: \exists n, m>N \land |x_n - x_m| \ge {1\over 8}
$$

Have i missed something?

Comment: It looks right to me.